# Excel : Numbers in one cell, Add in another Cell

Tags: excel

Is it possible to list a couple numbers in one cell ( without adding them) and show the result in another cell? Should look a little bit like this:

```
===========================================================
5+4+4+5+0+1+1+1,11 (first cell) == (second cell)    21,11==      
===========================================================
```

If so, how can it be done?

Thank you

Comment: Set the first cells data type to text, this will stop excel from evaluating the math and leave it as you wrote it. Assuming there's only ever one comma, splitting and evaluating then joining the data back up should be fairly easy to achieve with a formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Worksheet Solution

> *please note: this solution isn't recommended. It is sufficient if you only have one string to evaluate but not effective if you have multiple*

This makes use of the (hidden) `EVALUATE` function which I think can only be accessed using named ranges.

**Note** this doesn't work for the `,11` but will work with the other part of the string. I suggest you split those out and join them again after

1. Place your string (`5+4+4+5+0+1+1+1,11`) into cell **A1** (just for this example)
2. On the ribbon navigate to `Formulas>Name Manager`
3. Click `New` call the name "result" and type `=EVALUATE(A1)` in the "refers to:" field. Then click OK
4. Close the dialog box
5. In cell **B1** type `=result` and there you go

---

### VBA Solution

Your best option might be to use `VBA`. Using the `Evaluate` function made this task a bit easier as well. Place the code below into a new module in the VBA editor and use the following syntax on your worksheet:

```
=EvaluateString(A1)
```

this will return `21,11` for the input `5+4+4+5+0+1+1+1,11` as required

```
Function EvaluateString(rng As Range)
    Dim allNums As Variant
    allNums = Split(rng.Value, ",")

    Dim num As Variant
    Dim result As String
    For num = 0 To UBound(allNums)
        result = result & Application.Evaluate(allNums(num)) & ","
    Next num

    EvaluateString = Left(result, Len(result) - 1)
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It's exactly what I needed. But it actually works with .11 too, which is awesome!

Comment: No problem, happy to help